# FedEx post-order process in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, onepage-checkout, fedex

I have integrated FedEx (Test Mode) in Magento CE 1.9 and also able to place order successfully.
Here is screenshot from One page checkout screen for FedEx shipping options.. 
[image]

How to get tracking number for placed order? and how FedEx shipping process can be initiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a Fedex Account and then you will need to get Fedex Web Services Credentials in order to process your shipments using Magento.
If you do not get Fedex Web Services Credentials Magento will only show you rates as you have shown in your post.
However, if you want to function properly and do shipments and get tracking numbers you will need to work with Fedex and get proper credentials.
This is a process ....you can "START" by going to the fedex developer web pages.

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

hope this helps you get answers you need.
p.s. be patient Fedex can be confusing.

good Luck

~B.